# D3.js Wrapping of long labels alignment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js

I am using a tutorial from [Tutorialink Wrapping Text in D3](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/wrapping-text-in-d3/) which along with every other online resource, references [Mike Bostock’s “Wrapping Long Labels” example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) as it seems to be the only way to wrap labels in d3.

This is the result of my wrapping which is not ideal as I want them to be aligned to the centre. Please help as I am a noob in d3, any help would be appreciated!

[image: Label Wrapping]

This is my function wrap, and its implementation is found below it:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function () {
      var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(" ").reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 0.7, // ems
          x = text.attr("x"),
          y = text.attr("y"),
          dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
          tspan = text.text(null)
                      .append("tspan")
                      .attr("x", x)
                      .attr("y", y)
                      .attr("dy", dy + "em");
      while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
              line.pop();
              tspan.text(line.join(" "));
              line = [word];
              tspan = text.append("tspan")
                          .attr("x", x)
                          .attr("y", y)
                          .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                          .text(word);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Implementation of the node label on the 5th last line:

```
let nodeLabel = svg
        .selectAll(".nodeLabel")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text((d) => {
          if (d.label === "Company" && d.properties.name.length > 10)
            return d.properties.name.substring(0, 10) + "...";
          else if (d.label === "Story" && d.properties.name.length > 20)
            return d.properties.name.substring(0, 20) + "...";
          else return d.properties.name.substring(0, 10) + "...";
        })
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("dy", "1.8em")
        .attr("class", () => "label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", (f) => {
          if (f.label === "Company" || f.label === "Story") return "white";
          else return "black";
        })
        .call(wrap, 30) // wrap the text in <= 30 pixels
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .on("mouseover", (d) => {
          handleMouseover(d);
        });
```

Comment: You `<text>` elements don't have `x` and `y` attributes. See a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/shreshthmohan/pen/jOaJMpX) here. The wrap function uses `x` and `y` values.

Comment: @Shreshth thanks and well spotted! Problem is my nodes are completely random as this is a force-directed graph, so I am unable to determine the coordinates of my text node.

Comment: So are you using ‘transform’ to position the nodes? If yes, just set x and y both to 0.